# What is the name of this type design? (royal, classy, luxury)

Tags: terminology, style-identification

[image: *enter image description here*]

[image]

I am trying to find on internet that kind of type designs, but I do not know what is the terminology of this type. It should be barocco art, old classical ornaments, luxury? How exactly it is called in design?

Comment: There is no exact name. One could argue that the two pieces you show are of different styles

Comment: I agree with Zach here--the first piece is really classic and somewhat rococo, the second is *very* art déco.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the corner stylings and close similarities to the art deco style, I'd suggest *art nouveau* as it was a more, free flowing stye as opposed to the sharp lines of deco.

Comment: Hi Morgan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: In that case, based on the corner stylings and close similarities to the art deco style, this is my reason for suggesting art nouveau as it was a more, free flowing stye as opposed to the sharp lines of deco.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and [edit]ed that info into your answer. Feel free to re-[edit] when I mangled things too much beyond recognition!

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it myself "vintage luxury", pretty much of the ornamental style and luxury combined. I don't think that there is an unique name.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's Rococo style with some Victorian patterns.

Comment: Hi Iulian, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!